# Check if you're in the correct folder without generating a file in Angular

Tags: angular, command-line, command

I've been trying to find a command to check if I'm in the correct folder before generating a component in Angular.

For example I'd have multiple folders and subfolders and I before I generate a component with "ng g c folder/subfolder/subfolder/user-component" I want to check whether I'm in the correct folder before I generate it.

Is there a command I can use to check the folder structure instead of manually navigating to it with "cd"?

Comment: `dir` on Windows, `ls` on macOS or Linux. They'll give you the folder contents, which will help. Otherwise if you're using an IDE, you can right-click the folder you're aiming for in the file explorer and open a terminal there.

Answer (score 0):

So when you generate a new Component/Directive/Class etc.
The path that you give in the CLI

```
ng g c folder/subfolders.../filename
```

//the "folder" (first folder name) is looked into the app directory which is there since you created the project if it exists the component is created inside it otherwise the folder is first created then the file is created inside it.
Same is application to subfolders

Ex: ng g c shared/header/left

This means create 'left' component inside app/shared/header folders.